# PHP library for converting HTML4 to XHTML?

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I need to convert HTML4 input to valid XHTML (strict) in PHP5 for further processing (SAX for instance). Any suggestions?

Comment: http://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/tidying-up-html-code-with-tidy-php-extension

Answer (score 11):

The [PHP Tidy extension](http://php.net/tidy) should be able to do the job.

Here's a good article about it: [Tidying up HTML Code with Tidy PHP Extension](https://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/tidying-up-html-code-with-tidy-php-extension/).